# Dropdownlist based on dropdownlist C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, cascadingdropdown

I have 3 dropdownlists and I already set dropdownlist 2 based on `SelectedValue` of dropdownlist 1, but my dropdownlist 3 has no response based on selection in dropdownlist2

```
if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue =="1")
{
    DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
    DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("A", ""));
    DropDownList2.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("B", ""));
}
```

This is how I add items in `Dropdownlist2` based on selection in `Dropdownlist1` but it does not work in the third dropdownlist whic does not have any item after I select A in `Dropdownlist2`:

```
if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "0")
{
    DropDownList3.Items.Clear();
    DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("A-1", ""));
}
```

Comment: are you able to debug the code? Does is execute the code of populating DropDownList3 ? When these two codes are executed?

Comment: it should be `selectedIndex` not `selectedvalue` right? added an answer and explanation

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the only problem here is the dropdownlist 3 does not have any item after i selected something in dropdownlist 2

Comment: If you debug the code, you can figure out why it is not adding any items in DropDownList3. @HollowLooi

Answer (score 1):

i think you got the `selectedvalue` wrong, i think it should be `selectedindex`

```
if (DropDownList2.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    DropDownList3.Items.Clear();
    DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("A-1", ""));
}
```

if you will still want to use `selectedvalue` change the bindings of `new ListItem("A", "")` to `new ListItem("A", "");`

```
//populate first ddl with corret item and value
if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue =="1")
{
            DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("A", ""));
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("B", ""));
}

if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "A")
{
    DropDownList3.Items.Clear();
    DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("A-1", ""));
}
```

`DropdownList.Items.Insert` implements `ddl.Items.Insert(indexPosition, new ListItem("displayItem", "value");`

so since you are searching for "0" in the `selectedvalue` which in your example does not exists since `new ListItem("A", "")` it will not execute the statement inside

Comment: I changed into index, but the third dropdownlist still show blank for me

Comment: @HollowLooi can you show your code for the implementation of the dropdownlist?

Comment: Do you mean the whole function or ?